# excel Calendar and HYPERLINK

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I want to make a calendar and when I click on cell (date) I want that it link me to different sheet and cell

```
=Days+DATE(CalYear;MONTH($B$9);1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(CalYear;MONTH($B$9);1);(WeekStart="Monday")+1)+$A12*7-6)

=HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address";Sheet2!D1);Name of the cell)
```

I want to combine them together.

```
=HYPERLINK("#"&CELL("address";Sheet2!D1);Days+DATE(CalYear;MONTH($B$9);1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(CalYear;MONTH($B$9);1);(WeekStart="Monday")+1)+$A12*7-6))
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible, but I don't understand everything you've got going on in either forumlas. The format for a hyperlink formula is `=HYPERLINK(Link_location, Link_word)` so you would put the location your linking to in the first part, then you would encase your date formula in parentheses for the second part:

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!D1", (Days+DATE(CalYear;MONTH($B$9);1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(CalYear;MONTH($B$9);1);(WeekStart="Monday")+1)+$A12*7-6)
```

Like I said, I have no idea what you are doing in the first formula so you would have to edit that until it worked.